# Из массива объектов с помощью цикла в другой массив объектов записать определенные ключи и их значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
// examples
// [
//   { name: 'Jason Mount', team: 'Manchester United', goals: 4 },
//   { name: 'Jason Mount, team: 'Manchester United', goals: 0 },
//   { name: 'Finne Bard', team: 'Fulham United', goals: 1 },
//   { name: 'Gerhardt Yannick', team: 'Liverpool', goals: 8 },
// ];

const players = [
  {
    name: 'Jason Mount',
    birthdate: '19.12.1993',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: '21',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    position: 'MF',
    goals: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jason Mount',
    birthdate: '01.01.2001',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: '16',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    position: 'MF',
    goals: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Finne Bard',
    birthdate: '13.02.1995',
    country: 'Norwegen',
    number: '26',
    position: 'FW',
    team: 'Fulham United',
    goals: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Gerhardt Yannick',
    birthdate: '13.03.1994',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: 31,
    position: 'MF',
    team: 'Liverpool',
    goals: 8,
  },
];

>Вот мой пример, но выходит не то что нужно.

//
function getGoalsStat(players) {
    let arr = [];
    let obj = {};
    for (let item in players) {
        arr.push(obj.name = players[item].name);
        arr.push(obj.team = players[item].team);
        arr.push(obj.goals = players[item].goals);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const players = [
  {
    name: 'Jason Mount',
    birthdate: '19.12.1993',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: '21',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    position: 'MF',
    goals: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jason Mount',
    birthdate: '01.01.2001',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: '16',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    position: 'MF',
    goals: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Finne Bard',
    birthdate: '13.02.1995',
    country: 'Norwegen',
    number: '26',
    position: 'FW',
    team: 'Fulham United',
    goals: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Gerhardt Yannick',
    birthdate: '13.03.1994',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: 31,
    position: 'MF',
    team: 'Liverpool',
    goals: 8,
  },
];


function getGoalsStat(players) {
    let arr = [];
    
    for (let player of players) {      
        arr.push({ name: player.name, team: player.team, goals: player.goals });                
    }
    return arr;
};

console.log(getGoalsStat(players));
```

---

Упрощённо:

```js
const players = [
  {
    name: 'Jason Mount',
    birthdate: '19.12.1993',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: '21',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    position: 'MF',
    goals: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jason Mount',
    birthdate: '01.01.2001',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: '16',
    team: 'Manchester United',
    position: 'MF',
    goals: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Finne Bard',
    birthdate: '13.02.1995',
    country: 'Norwegen',
    number: '26',
    position: 'FW',
    team: 'Fulham United',
    goals: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Gerhardt Yannick',
    birthdate: '13.03.1994',
    country: 'Deutschland',
    number: 31,
    position: 'MF',
    team: 'Liverpool',
    goals: 8,
  },
];

let getGoalsStat = (players) => players.map(player => ({ name: player.name, team: player.team, goals: player.goals }));


console.log(getGoalsStat(players));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!